# bxslider - if slider count is 1 or less don't autoplay

Tags: bxslider

Is there a way to code up bxslider to say that if the slide count = 1 then don't autoplay? if more than 1 do autoplay?

e.g. can I add an if statement to make this work?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it :)

```
auto:($(".bxslider > li").length > 1),
```